# OpenCV zero padding

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

I'm using `cvFilter2D` to filter images.  Its [documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/imgproc_image_filtering.html?highlight=filter2d) says:

> When the aperture is partially outside
>   the image, the function interpolates
>   outlier pixel values from the nearest
>   pixels that are inside the image.

While such extrapolation is fine in a majority of cases, I want to handle such outlier pixel values by **zero padding** (here's a 1D [example](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/st/Zero_Padding.html) of what this means).

Here's the way I'm currently doing it:

```
def do_filter(im, filt):
    N, M = cv.GetSize(filt)
    _, _, width, height = cv.GetImageROI(im)
    padded = cv.CreateImage((width + N, height + M), im.depth, im.nChannels)
    cv.SetZero(padded)
    roi = (N/2, M/2, width, height)
    cv.SetImageROI(padded, roi)
    cv.Copy(im, padded)
    cv.ResetImageROI(padded)
    cv.Filter2D(padded, padded, filt)
    result = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(im), im.depth, im.nChannels)
    cv.SetImageROI(padded, roi)
    cv.Copy(padded, result)
    return result
```

Basically:

- Create padded image and copy contents from input
- Filter
- Trim away padded areas

I don't like this because I have to do a lot of busy work just moving pixels around.  It's slow.

Is there a better way to do zero padding when filtering?

**EDIT**

I've found [cvCopyMakeBorder](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/imgproc_image_filtering.html?highlight=filter2d#cvCopyMakeBorder) which is slightly cleaner, but still copies the image, and is thus slow.

**EDIT 2**

[cv::filter2D](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_image_filtering.html?highlight=filter2d#filter2D) in the C++ API does this.  I'd like to know if the old C API has the same functionality buried somewhere (I can't access the C++ API from Python, but I can access the C API from Python).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind losing a the external 1-pixel thick edge of your image, you can set it to 0, and then the "interpolation" will give you what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but the black border artifact isn't acceptable for me.

Comment: Then you can embed the image is a larger image using cvCopyMakeBorder(), as you suggested, but it may be just a single (black) pixel larger and not the complete half-width of your kernel, and still achieve the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Python, but the in C/C++, you can specify that you want a certain constant to be used for the "undefined" pixels. Set this constant to 0, and you'll have your problem solved. I'm sure Python has something similar as well.

Comment: can you please provide a link to documentation that describes this?  C++ is OK (but C is better, since I can directly access that from Python).

Comment: filter2D(A, C, -1, kernel, Point(1,1), 0, BORDER_CONSTANT); - A - source, C - destination, -1 - depth, kernel - the kernel, Point(1, 1) - the anchor, 0 - the constant, BORDER_CONSTANT - pad the image with constants (for some reason, I couldn't find a documentation link for this :| )

Comment: OK, that's for the C++ API (it's cv::filter2D -- http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_image_filtering.html?highlight=filter2d#filter2D).  Do you know if it's possible with the old C API?